# drupalcommerce/project-base prohibits upgrade to Drupal 9.2.4

Tags: commerce, composer, 9

I'm running into composer errors while trying to update a Drupal Commerce site to Drupal 9.2.4.

I'm not sure how to interpret this output when I try `composer prohibits drupal/core 9.2.4`

results: https://pastebin.com/EWaDQejD

eg:
drupal/core                  9.2.4  requires          twig/twig (^2.12.0)
drupalcommerce/project-base  -      does not require  twig/twig (but v1.44.4 is installed)

Not sure what to do next. Also I can't upgrade admin_toolbar as it's not compatible (accord to Composer) with Commerce Base. Seems to be related.

Tried upgrading commerce base:
`composer require drupalcommerce/commerce_base:9.x-dev` but no love.

It used to be 1.x-dev.

Some instructions on how to update a Drupal 8 Commerce site (installed with composer as instructed) would be helpful.

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I managed to upgrade from 8.9.20 to 9.2.9

You need to add to your composer.json :

```
"repositories": {
  "drupal": {
    "type": "composer",
    "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
  },
  "commerce_base": {
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/drupalcommerce/commerce_base"
  },
  "asset-packagist": {
    "type": "composer",
    "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
  }
},
```

You can find it here line 17
https://github.com/drupalcommerce/project-base/blob/8.x/composer.json#L17

The answer was here : https://github.com/drupalcommerce/commerce_base/issues/5

I hope it helps you.